# Google Docs strike-through shortcut not working on Mac in Chrome

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

According to the menu, the shortcut is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, but it doesn't work.

It works in Safari, but not Chrome. I tried it on my old Mac (a few OS versions behind) and got the same result.

I even tried Incognito Mode (no plugins?) and it still doesn't work.

Also doesn't work in Google Sheets.

So it seems like Chrome is eating the shortcut keypress somehow? How could I fix or debug this?

Answer (score 21):

I eventually tested on a 3rd Mac and it worked. It turns out it was a Chrome extension using that same shortcut on my 2 Macs. I don't know why Incognito mode didn't solve this.

You can see the keyboard shortcuts claimed by your extensions here:

```
chrome://extensions/shortcuts
```

Comment: Darn you Pushbullet!

Comment: Pushbullet was also the culprit in my case. Thanks for tip!

Answer (score -2):

I have MacOS Mojave 10.14.2 and the <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> works great for a highlighted word(s) on my Chrome Gmail account.